# How to use OpenCV to transform the actual camera image to the original one?

Tags: java, opencv, transformation

Here is the original pad image that I created

[image: original pad]

and the actual captured image from the camera

[image: real pad].

I am looking for a highly accuracy way to transform the captured image back to the shape of the original one with respect to the positions of the white and lime green areas. I tried OpenCV with Feature detection but it could not detect any similar features between the two images (the key point sets of the two images are also totally different). Any suggestions or sample code in Java or C++ are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Since you know the original object, maybe you can detect the corners of the rectangle, and then find a homography between them, then you can just warp them. Here is a link for a [small tutorial](http://www.learnopencv.com/homography-examples-using-opencv-python-c/) about it. You may try it first selecting the points manually, to see how it works and if you like it, then try finding the edges and the corners

Comment: I also tried homography. However, it's impossible to use either SIFT or SURF feature detector in Java (or they are not available in my library). I tried ORB but it couldn't find any similar points.

Comment: The tutorial that you have sent is amazing :)

Comment: It is quite hard to get good features in such an homogeneous regions... I mean, it is impossible to distinguish which points in the edges is which. I would go with an approach using color threshold, and then getting the edges of the zone and finding the intersection of such edges. For the correspondance, it will require a little bit of more analysis or brute force